# "Identity-free" definition of an isomorphism in a semigroupoid / semicategory

Tags: category-theory

I am looking for a way to define "Isomorphism" in a semigroupoid (or semicategory), that is a "category", which does not necessarily have identities.

To be more specific I am looking for a way to make the following theorem work in semigroupoids:

> Initial objects (Terminal objects) are unique up to isomorphism.

So, actually I am looking for a notion of objects "being isomorphic" in semigroupoids. However, I am also interested in how said isomorphisms may look like.

---

I am still new to category theory and I am just asking this out of curiosity. I (briefly) read about "Equivalence of categories", which is kind of a relaxed "version" of categories being isomorphic, but as far as I know this definition only makes sense for objects in $\mathsf{Cat}$.

Comment: You could call $ f $ and $ g $ inverse to each other if $ gfg=g $ and $ fgf=f $.

Comment: Thanks; that's a great idea! However, I just realized that my question does not make any sense in relation to the theorem I want to proof. There is exactly one morphism $f$ from an initial object $0$ to itself. For all $g : 0 \rightarrow C$ for some object $C$ we have: $g \circ f = g$, since $g \circ f : 0 \rightarrow C$ but there is only one arrow from $0$ to $C$. Hence $f$ is a right-identity. So the theorem should follow, if we relax the definition of isomorphisms, so that $f \circ f^{-1}$ is a one-sided identity. Can I answer my own question or should I delete it?

Comment: This question is already more than 4 years old, so pardon my late comment. But this specific question is discussed in [this ar$\chi$iv preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.3524). I think it may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know, where my head was. It's simpler than it seemed:

Let $f$ be an isomorphism, if there exists a morphism $g$, such that $g\circ f$ is a one-sided identity.

Then we have:

> Initial objects (Terminal objects) are unique up to isomorphism.

Proof:
Observe, that there is unique endomorphism $f$ on an initial object $0$. Then for all objects $C$ and morphisms $g : 0 \rightarrow C$ we have: $g\circ f = g$, since
there is only one morphism from $0$ to $C$. Hence, $f$ is a right-identity.

Let $0$ and $0'$ be initial objects. Denote their right-identities as $f$ and $f'$ respectively. Let $g : 0 \rightarrow 0'$ and $g' : 0' \rightarrow 0$ be morphisms. Then $g'\circ g= f$ and $g \circ g' = f'$, that is $g$ is iso and $0 \cong 0'$.

The result for terminal objects follows from duality. Observe, that dually the endomorphism on a terminal object is a left-identity. $\square$

---

Is this correct and does it make sense?